# TeXmaker unable to find packages after installing texlive-full

Tags: packages, texlive, texmaker

I know this isn't the TeXmaker forum, but I was hoping someone had the same problem. Also, if someone knows the official texmaker forum please link it.

I had a problem with algorithm2e and someone suggested installing texlive-full. So I did, and now my texmaker can't find (most) packages and just returns:

'Undefined control sequence.'

On these lines:

```
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

Might downgrading to texlive work? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi! Can you please let us know what operating system do you use? It is in general [advised not to install the TeXLive version provided by linux distros](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=109427).

Comment: There are a `algorithm2e` package in your system? In case of a TeXLive from Debian/ubuntu distribution, this `algorithm2e` is in `texlive-science` package. Do a `sudo apt-get install texlive-science`. In other case **do not try** the above and do `tlmgr install algorithm2e`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, and sorry about the poor format. I'm running Ubuntu server, and I will try to make the format more clear.

Comment: As it stands, I don't think we can answer this. We need a lot more detail.